# Ruby on Rails JQuery not loading at appropriate time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery

I have problem which I can't figure out. Here is the code

```
$('.new').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#y').load('/y/y #x'), function(e) {};             
    showadd(); // function to call modal
    $("#x").attr("data-remote","true"); // making :remote => true 
});
```

Now What problem is that I would like to bind success on the form I loaded with above code. The only problem is that It doesn't work ! It works only after I added from the console.

so my binding function

```
$('#x').bind('ajax:success', function(evt, data, status, xhr){
    alert("YES");
});
```

Now It doesn't work if I put mentioned code in the $('.new').click( ...
Only If I added via console.

Is there a way to remove all other binding events associated with one element, and add one from each call of function ?

I would like to do something like this for example

```
function makingAjaxRespond() {
// remove all associated binding with the form
// add one binding
// confirm that binding has been added
}
```

I'm having really hard time figuring the firstly mentioned issue. Is there any very simple way that I'm missing ?

Thanks for your help and consideration in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use the [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method instead, it sounds like your method might not be getting binded because the object doesn't exist at the time?

Try something like:

```
$(document).on('ajax:success', '#x', function(evt, data, status, xhr){
    alert("YES");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you seeing any errors in the console? The issue is like that you're either attempting to use `$` before jQuery has been included, or that you're attempting to select elements before the DOM is ready. The solution is the use `$(function () { ... })` and make sure it's been output in your document *after* the `<script src=...>` which includes jQuery.